# Mt. Everest Hyperloop- Reborn

Tags: space-travel, megastructures, propulsion

In my [previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/234454/i-designed-a-maglev-space-propulsion-tube-on-mt-everest-do-you-see-any-issues), I was discussing about the possibility of using a mass-driver on Mt. Everest, to propel payloads to space, and reduce the amount of fuel needed (RIP bulky rockets). A diagram below of my former design:[image]

However, there was a ton of issues with this design:

- Dangling a tube from a balloon is a really risky idea as the balloon can be torn apart by the wind and jet-stream on top of Mt. Everest. This could result in collapse of the structure. Firing a payload is even worse, as a tube that is dangling could suddenly jerk and tear the balloon cord,  with catastrophic consequences.
- The Himalayas are an earthquake zone. The structure would break apart during earthquakes.
- Even if you managed not to exceed 3-4gs acceleration, then the curve above the ground could cause a dramatic acceleration spike, this can lead to serious consequences for astronauts.
- Mass drivers may work on airless planets like Moon and Mercury, but on Earth, the air is thick enough to burn the payload long before it attained orbit.

So, after a lot of thoughts, and ideas, I came up with a grander and more realistic design for the **Mt. Everest Maglev Accelerator**, this time with no ridiculous balloons, or spikes. So here is the design and its principles.

## Design

- This design consists of a large tube that is erected on giant graphene rods about 10 inches wide in diameter. This provides immense strength, as graphene is strong enough not to crush its base and be rigid.
- This design is a **ring-gun magnet** type accelerator. This means that the magnets are placed in rings that have the same poles facing the track. The interior of the tube would look sort of like this:[image]
- Cross-section of propulsion tube.[image]
- The ring-magnets are still permanent and have a greater strength of 10 teslas. They are not electromagnets.
- The payload itself is attached with ring-magnets with like poles, i.e. south pole facing outwards. This generates strong repulsion that propel the rocket at high speeds. The ring-magnet themselves are reusable, they are detached from the payload, and fall back to earth, whereas the payload will gain even more momentum, due to conservation of I-can't-remember, as the ring-magnets are detached.
- The tube viewed above from ground, looks sort of like this. (Apologies, I am crappy at photoshop, so this is the best depiction I can make). It is about 30 km tall, and stretches into the lower stratosphere.

[image]

- The tube's actual length is however astounding. It is about 500 km long, and is mostly built underground. It is made of titanium in order to withstand the stress and pressure from the weight of the mountains above it, and withstands earthquakes.
- The curve of the tube is gradual instead of sudden, as to prevent "jerks"(i.e. sudden high-Gs)

## Principles

The aim of the <s>mass driver</s> Maglev Accelerator is to make it travel so fast, that it won't have time to burn up in the atmosphere. I mean literally fast. The payload's velocity upon exiting the barrel is about 60-70 km/s (yes, Kms per second). The idea came from the [Plumbbob Pascal-B Borecap](https://www.businessinsider.com/fastest-object-robert-brownlee-2016-2?IR=T#since-then-brownlees-concludedit-was-going-too-fast-to-burn-up-before-reaching-outer-spaceafter-i-was-in-the-business-and-did-my-own-missile-launches-he-said-i-realized-that-that-piece-of-iron-didnt-have-time-to-burn-all-the-way-up-in-the-atmosphere-14), where it was theorised that it was moving so fast that it had literally no time to burn up in the atmosphere before reaching space.

Although this would mean that the payload is moving too fast for it to be able to remain in orbit (about 6x Earth's Escape Velocity), that is not a problem as this accelerator is meant for interplanetary journey, such as travelling to Saturn, Mars and Moon. I will discuss a **orbit-grade accelerator** in a future question, but for now, this accelerator cannot be used for orbiting payloads.

The reason why I am using Mt. Everest and not Chimborazo for the accelerator, is that Mt. Everest is actually closer to space than Chimborazo is. This may seem odd, but Mt. Everest's 9km height makes it closer to space than Chimborazo's 6km is. Although Earth being oblate makes Chimborazo cheat and get "taller" technically, Everest is still the victor, as the atmosphere is oblate like the Earth. The air pressure at the top of Mt. Chimborazo is just that at sea-level, whereas the air at the top of Mt. Everest is literally a partial vacuum, with just over a third that at sea-level. Everest's great height also provides structural support to the colossal accelerator to reach the required velocity.

**Is this design more better for propelling payloads/passengers to space? If no, then what flaws do I have to fix?**

Clarifications:

- No, this accelerator is absolutely not used for orbital journeys. This accelerator is used for interplanetary journeys, such as Earth-Mars, or Earth-Saturn journeys

Note: I'd like to avoid extended discussions in comments, as I have created [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140455/mt-everest-maglev-accelerator-v2) for this question.

Comment: Your conclusions re: Pascal B seem very different than [those reached by Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/489471) when they took a shot at the problem.

Comment: I'm also a bit unsure how you're supposed to get a speed boost from staging the ring-magnets from the payload. Unless you apply thrust after separation with, e.g., a rocket, magnet and payload will follow pretty much the same path.

Comment: @Cadence As the rocket loses mass, the magnets transfer their momentum to the payload, increasing velocity. I think it has something to do with Conservation of Momentum or smth. But the principle is, **The lighter you get, the faster you go**

Comment: Just dropping magnets isn't going to do anything to accelerate the payload further. Of course, the permanent magnet rings aren't going to accelerate the payload in the first place...

Comment: @FuriousArcturus Momentum is indeed conserved: when the vehicle separates, the payload gets its share of momentum and the magnet gets its share. You can't magically declare that the payload gets all of it and the magnet gets none, that isn't how conservation works.

Comment: What does "RIP bulky rockets" mean, particularly in light of "google.com/search?q=RIP+bulky+rockets&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB779GB779&oq=RIP+bulky+rockets&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.4111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"

Comment: Why, please, did you not run your Posts through a spell-checker?

Comment: If you put a partial vacuum inside the tube, you might have something. Pushing a plug of air through the tube at that speed would create a LOT of heat.

Comment: Suspend it from an orbital platform like a space elevator.

Comment: Generally it is considered good practice to wait a few days before assigning the Checkmark to an answer.

Comment: Another minor issue is that at 4 *g* acceleration and 60 km/s exit velocity, the structure would need to be about 46000 km long, not 500 km.

Answer (score 11):

### Impossibility 1: Ring magnets as depicted

All magnetic fields need to be closed curves. The ring magnet as depicted would require a magnetic source at the very center of the ring, which is forbidden.

The problem can be alleviated by placing many magnets on the outside in the correct orientation but with small wedge-shaped gaps between every two magnets. Technically you only need a few (1-3) long magnet rail tracks, which allows orientation control of the payload and considerably reduces construction costs.

It's by the way better to use permanent magnets *attracting* to the track than repulsing from it, that way the payload can not *overturn* and slip out of the magnetic track. A simple set of ring motors could be used to give the capsule any wanted orientation by rotating the magnet tracks around the tube or their receptors on the payload - even allowing to simulate *rifling* to achieve spin stabilization.

### Impossibility 2: only permanent magnet accelerator

The maglev track is perfect to get minimal drag, and as explained above, does work. However, it does not accelerate on its own - it simply provides a means to have extremely low friction to the guide rail.

If you take a slice from real Maglev trains, a set of coils inside the train car is electrified to create repulsing forces in some areas and attracting in others, which all in all accelerate the vehicle.

### Impossibility 3: architectural constraints

You have a $\pu{30 km}$ pipe extending for up to about $\pu{22 km}$ above the point we leave the tip of Mt Everest. It is supported on stilts up to $\pu{25 km}$ long, assuming that the highland below is *just* about $\pu{5 km}$ above sea level. That is well beyond what **any** material can do. Steel is typically blessed with allowing $\pu{25000 psi}\ (\pu{172 MPa})$ compressible force before failure, which is [6 times that of concrete](https://blog.redguard.com/compressive-strength-of-steel). But well-made steel can get better, up to $\pu{250 MPa}$ are possible. That's $\pu{250 000 000 N/m² }$. Above that, the column collapses under its own weight

But the column itself weighs a lot: assuming we have a crossection of one square meter of steel, then each meter height (and thus each cubic-meter) weighs 7.85 tons $(\pu{7850 kg})$, exerting roughly $\pu{78500 N}$ each. At which point *stacking bricks* makes the lowest one crumble? Well... incidentally the compressive strength would itself allow for being 3184.71 meters tall. so roundabout 3 Kilometers. Or at **best** a tiny fraction of the pillar length needed to support the tube - and we haven't even assigned any weight to that.

The pipe goes up to maybe 10 kilometers... and then it breaks down, having to end as it can't be supported with any material or construction.

Exotic materials, such as Graphene fare much worse: Graphene's compressive strength is [only](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5020547) $\pu{8.5 MPa}$ under normal conditions but could be driven to $\pu{28.8 MPa}$ at $\pu{2267 kg/m³}$. As a result for a maximum pillar height of Graphene is just $\pu{375 m}$ or, with the special tricks,
$\pu{1270 m}$

A 10-inch graphene rod fares exactly the same: It has $\pu{78.5 in²}$ or almost exactly $\pu{0.05 m²}$ area. Let's keep that. It can sustain the same pressure before collapsing, so the lowest piece can carry $\pu{0.05m²}\times \pu{28.8 kg/m²}$ load. Each Meter height weighs in at $\pu{0.05m³}\times \pu{2267kg/m³}$. As a result, we get exactly the same height for a stable column as before: 375 to $\pu{1270 m}$.

Comment: The stilts are made of graphene

Comment: @FuriousArcturus Graphene? Really? [Graphene only can be compressed 8.5 MPa](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5020547) before crumbling. It can be *pulled* a lot, but not compressed.

Comment: Don't forget the compressive strength of the mountain that you're setting this thing on, which for granite might be [something like 130 MPa](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/compression-tension-strength-d_1352.html). Stilts are useless if they end up gouging out the ground beneath them.

Comment: @Cadence or sinking the island they sit on. Looking at you, Venice!

Comment: @Trish Haha in your face Venice!

Comment: And in addition a  25 centimeters thick, 25 kilometer tall column would be definitive illustration for [buckling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling).

Answer (score 10):

Though I don't see any reference to it in this question or your previous one, you should probably read about [StarTram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarTram), because it was a project that considers many of the same things you're looking at. The StarTram authors used to have all their interesting stuff available for free on their website, but the main ebook is now paid-only.

StarTram uses an evacuated tube with a "conventional" superconducting electromagnetic accelerator.

Here's a diagram that looks a little like your own:

[image: Star tram gen one and gen two diagrams, showing horizontal acceleration paths which run up a mountainside so that the projectile exits high in the atmosphere so as to minimize drag forces. The Gen 2 diagram shows the massive superconducting structure that supports the muzzle at some 20km altitude]

The Gen 1 design, which has the muzzle of the accelerator at the top of a suitable mountain, is intended for cargo only as it has a 30G peak acceleration and a 6-12G peak decelleration when it hits the atmosphere upon exiting the muzzle. It uses a clever [plasma window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_window) to maintain vacuum in the tube but still allow the projectile to egress the accelerator. It comes out at near orbital velocity, requiring some small boost rockets (<1km/s delta-V) to finish the job.

The Gen 2 design uses a somewhat gonzo electromagnetic repulsion architecture using massive supercondcting cables. I won't regurgitate the exact details of this here, but suffice to say that the authors were well aware that massive scaffolding structures and balloons can't work. Whether or not their solution would is something I won't consider here.

[image: A star tram gen 2 accellerator muzzle, showing a craft exiting the accelerator at 20km altitude, and a series of tethers that fasten the tube to the ground against the repulsion force generated by superconducting cables along the length of the accelerator]

(image credit [NASA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Startramgeneration2.jpg))

> The high altitude evacuated launch tube has a set of high current superconducting (SC) cables that magnetically interact with a second set of high current SC cables on the surface beneath to create a magnet levitation force of several metric tons per meter of tube length. The levitation force is greater than the weight of the launch tube plus its SC cables and tethers, resulting in a net upward force on the structure. In turn, the levitated structure is anchored to the ground by a network of high tensile strength, lightweight Kevlar or Spectra tethers

So, now I've shown you the competition, lets look at the details of your design.

1. Permanent magnet accelerator

I can't see that this could ever work, even if you could get powerful enough permanent magnets (you probably can't) in sufficient quantity (you probably can't) that are light enough for your 30km high suspended section to work (almost certainly no). Just use a superconducting electromagnetic accelerator... it is something that could conceivably be built with present-day technology, after all.

2. Giant graphene rods

Graphene has excellent tensile strength, but its compressive strength is less exciting, and a 30km tall tower that needs to withstand launch stresses and weather patterns is a fearsome undertaking to say the least. Other answers already go into more detail on this matter, but if you want a structure this tall then it needs to be suspended by some other means. I won't go into detail on this here, but maybe you could ask another question?

3. 60km/s muzzle velocity

Brownlee lamented the commonly repeated story of the Pascal B test, because it resulted in a lot of people mocking his terrible understanding of aerodynamics. He just estimated the speed of the cap, but made no claims about it getting into space, and assumed it was vaporized in the lower atmosphere.

Anyway, that niggle aside, I'm not sure you've necessarily consider the effects of hitting the atmosphere, even at 30km, at that sort of speed. Sure, the projectile will not be in the atmosphere for long, but not being there long enough to slow down below orbital velocity or burn up is not the same  as being safe for the cargo. The initial forces on leaving the muzzle of the accelerator are too difficult for me to calculate, but I'm pretty certain they'll be extremely unpleasant if not outright dangerous.

I'm not going to commit to these figures, but at an atmospheric density of ~0.01841kg/m<sup>3</sup> ([wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=density%20of%20air%20at%2030000m)), a vehicle with a drag coefficient of 0.09 (from the StarTram design)  and travelling at 60 km/s is going to experience a drag force of the order of 10MN. A mass of 40 tonnes (from the StarTram design) will therefore experience a (probably transient) acceleration of ~24 gravities. That is a potentially aorta-dissecting amount of acceleration to apply to a human cargo, especiially given how rapidly it will be applied. For more reading on the subject, have a read of some of the many papers on the subject... here's one I found with a minute or two of searching: [Human Tolerance to Rapidly Applied Accelerations](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19980228043).

I might be quite wrong here, but you're talking about a speed far too high to be safe even in a fairly thin atmosphere.

> Is this design more better for propelling payloads/passengers to space? If no, then what flaws do I have to fix?

Honestly, your design seems to be a combination of overkill and, uh, not-enough-kill.

Lets gloss over whether or not the passengers of your craft will die instantly as their coffin leaves the muzzle of your death-cannon for now (but I suspect that the flight is likely to be physically traumatic if not fatal) and consider the other aspects of your idea.

The StarTram design dealt with merely surface-to-orbit construction, with the reasonable assumption that if you've cracked the difficult issue of getting out of the Earth's gravity well then you can built much more appropriate interplanetary infrastructure in space.

Thing is, your fixed accelerator makes it very difficult to aim... you get to fiddle with muzzle velocity to some degree, but everything else is limited by time of year and time of day. This in turn limits the number of targets you can reach in a convenient timespan. From space though, you have much more flexibility.

Even aside from that is the issue of safety... a suborbital flight that requires active boosting into orbit can fail safe (assuming your launch vehicles can safely re-enter, which you should ensure) because you re-enter and can land. Your capsule on the other hand is not only going much faster than terrestrial escape velocity, but can easily exceed solar escape velocity! At Earth's orbit, solar escape velocity is ~42km/s. Earth's own orbital velocity is 30km/s, which means unless you're shooting in a retrograde direction then any problems mean you shoot out into interstellar space, and rescue is likely to be challenging.

Don't be so impatient. You can launch your interplanetary vehicle into orbit and renezvous with a secondary propulsion system (eg. laser ablative, or plasma-push magsail or whatever) to hoof you in the right direction at the right time. The additional wait isn't going to be more than an hour or two, and the additional safety and considerable reduction in your accelerator size, cost and complexity will be well worth the tradeoff.

(Note that you already have to have some kind of mechanism to impart a delta-V of tens of kilometers per second to your capsule, because you have to slow it down at its destination! As this is a required ability anyway, you may as well use it for the boost phase as well as the brake phase and save yourself a lot of hassle)

Answer (score 3):

> Is this design more better for propelling payloads/passengers to space? If no, then what flaws do I have to fix?

**Two Big Flaws**

1. How does it stay up?
2. How come it's so fast?

You claim the graphite stilts will support the track no problem. How are they so dang strong? I feel safe to assume that no known material is strong enough to support a 30km tall 500km railway on stilts alone. The Earth moves and the air moves.

I suggest you replace the stilts with a 500km tall solid unobtanium pyramid.

On second thoughts why do we need supports at all? Just point Space Tube sideways. You need to launch things sideways to get to orbit anyway. And launching in a straight line in any direction will get you into space:

[image]

You will need some supports if you desire a perfectly straight tube. But it is not obvious why that would help. Just accelerate along the Earth's curvature instead of a straight line. Of course the image is only accurate if the Earth is round. If your Earth is flat then your Space Ramp Tube is a good idea.

The second problem, is how you claim the projectile exits at 40km/s. But how does it go so dang fast? You explain how it is levitated but not how it is accelerated. Maglev stuff, sure, there are real Maglev trains and they work somehow. But those bad boys go only 100ish m/s. That's much slower than Space Tube. Maybe Space Tube uses Particle accelerator tech to go fast. Those things are lined with magnets too. And they go very fast indeed. But particles are famously smaller than spaceships.

There is also this:

> Mass drivers may work on airless planets like Moon and Mercury, but on Earth, the air is thick enough to burn the payload long before it attained orbit.

You give this problem but don't explain your solution. It sounds like Space Tube Mk. II is just as vulnerable to burning up as Space Tube Mk I. To fix this I suggest the inside of the tube have all the air pumped out.

Comment: Mass driver propels payloads to high enough speeds so that it has no time to burn up in the air

Comment: @FuriousArcturus How does that work?

Comment: The faster you go, the more the air will compress in front of the projectile instead of being deflected to the sides, and the denser and hotter the plasma will be, not to mention the mechanical forces scaling...well, you're well beyond the point where they scale merely with the square of airspeed. They scale *inconveniently*. In short, the very concept of there being a "high enough speed" to escape the atmosphere is likely faulty.

Comment: "... perfectly staight tube. But it is not obvious why that would help" Sure it is. It gets you out of the atmosphere. That way when you suddenly leave the vacuum of the tube you wont suddenly go splat against all that air. Otherwise you're doing a heat shield requiring reentry in reverse. But done this way all you have to worry about is environmentalists complaining about all the earth quakes your support pyramid is causing.

Comment: @candied_orange I have suggested the tube have the air pumped out.

Comment: @candied_orange It is silly to disagree with someone who says something is not obvious.

Comment: @Daron fun too.

Answer (score 1):

Ditch Everest. Switch to Chimborazo in Ecuador. Two reasons:

1. Because it is closer to the equator, it's peak is actually farther from the center of the Earth.
2. Because it is closer to the equator, you get more of a boost from rotation of the Earth. Everest at 29.59 degrees North loses almost 14% of the rotational velocity.

So launching from Chimborazo gets you additional altitude, and about 223 km/hr extra launch velocity.

The structure you have envisioned is massively beyond our current tech. At both ends.

Digging a slanted tunnel roughly 100 km long is getting to silly proportions. The [deepest mine right now is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_deepest_mines) 4 km deep. This is getting pretty close to the limits of our tech right now.

The truss you envision holding the launch tube is grotesquely beyond what we can build now.

The launch energy needs to be supplied. You need electromagnets up the length of the tube. The energy they need to supply, assuming a constant acceleration, increases as the speed increases. So you need to run gargantuan power cables up the structure as well.

You might get someplace by forgetting the extension above and below the mountain. You could have some sort of electromagnetic launcher that pushed a sled that carried your orbiter. Assuming a 50 km track and only 1g, you get 1 km/s in 100 seconds, pretty close to Mach 1, up the mountain. This is fast enough that the sled could detach and the orbiter take over its own burn. The first 25 km or so of the track would be level then curve up the mountain.

There are lots of variations on this. For example, the sled could also be a rocket motor that acted as a first stage. Or you could amp up the acceleration up the hill. At 4 g you get pretty close to Mach 2, in 25 seconds.

You can get an idea of what you are gaining from launching from the mountain. At 4g you are basically getting the first 25 seconds of rocket power from your launch sled. Suppose you were able to build the truss and extend the ramp another 50 km. This gives you only about another 10 seconds. The part on the mountain might be worth it. Building this currently-impossible truss seems to be a diminishing return.

Comment: In other words, same answer as last time.  Distance from Earth's center and rotational velocity mean more than atmospheric pressure at the mountaintop, because you won't spend long in that atmosphere (a minute or so, maximum).